Who Owns the IP Rights? Invention Outside Company Market
I work for a company that manufacturers X commercial machines. I have come up with a new invention that can be sold in the fixture components market (completely unrelated to the products my company produces and the market we work in). I did design it on company time with the intent for using it in an application, but it is still in the design concept phase (nothing has physically been produced yet).
I do not recall ever signing any documents with "invent for hire" clause and inventing new components is not a necessary part of my job. I can easily use "off the shelf" components for completing my work assignments.
Does the company still own the rights to the intellectual property of my invention? Can I patent my design and sell it to the open market?

If you never signed an assignment agreement, it falls in a legal grey area called "implied consent to an assignment". https://beckerlawllc.com/who-owns-your-companys-intellectual-property/ Some research may be required to determine how this doctrine applies in the particular state you are employed under the laws of. You may consider updating the question to include the state detail.

First off, I am not a lawyer. For most people working for employers, if they are paying you, they own the fruits of your labor. This is the standard way things work. Now your situation may be different and to get a definitive opinion you should consult with a lawyer.
Ethically, if it were me, I would disclose the invention to my employer. If it were really of no value to their business, they may well just let you just do with it what you want. But again, that is me. The most prudent course is consulting with a lawyer.
